# Create runspace fails

Tags: c#, powershell, exception

**Problem:**

Hello, I want to play with the powershell in a c# program. 
I tried some samples from the web and here, but they all fail to create the runspace with an InvalidProgramException. Powershell is installed on my machine (Windows7 64bit) and I can use it when I start it from the start menu (I assume x86 and x64 is installed and this might be the problem)

**Installed:**

- Windows PowerShell
- Windows PowerShell (x86)
- Windows PowerShell ISE
- Windows PowerShell ISE (x86)
- Windows PowerShell Modules

**Exception:**

```
Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.InvalidProgramException" ist in PowerShellExecutionSample.exe aufgetreten.

   bei System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
   bei PowerShellExecutionSample.PowerShellRunner.Run(IDictionary`2 parameters, String script) in c:\Temp\0601.PowerShellExecutionSample\PowerShellExecutionSample\PowerShellRunner.cs:Zeile 26.
   bei PowerShellExecutionSample.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Temp\0601.PowerShellExecutionSample\PowerShellExecutionSample\Program.cs:Zeile 20.
   bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
```

**Code:**

```
public void Run(string script, IDictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
{
    using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
    {
        runSpace.Open();

        using (Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
        {
            // In-vars
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var param in parameters)
                {
                    runSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable(param.Key, param.Value);
                }
            }

            // execute
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            // Out-vars
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var param in parameters)
                {
                    parameters[param.Key] = runSpace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue(param.Key);
                }
            }
        }

        runSpace.Close();
    }
}
```

**Question:**

Why does it fail? Does my program try to instantiate the wrong runspace (x86 v. x64)? Do I need to install a special version of the powershell or set some rights?

Comment: You could try using `PowerShell` class. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx

Comment: This is one of the samples I already tried and it fails with the same exception. I cannot create a runspace or a powershell instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to Powershell 4.0 (from Powerershell 3.0)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx